# Create xarray Dataset with observations and averages that has combined index

Tags: python, time-series, python-xarray

Suppose I have the following dataarray containing observations for different locations over time:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(42)

data = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randint(1,100, (36, 3)), 
    dims=("time", "location"), 
    coords={
        "time": pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=36, freq="10D"), 
        "location": ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    name="observations"
)
```

and now I calculate the monthly average and combine it with the observations to a dataset:

```py
monthly_avg = data.groupby("time.month").mean()
data = data.to_dataset()
data["average"] = monthly_avg
```

giving me

[image]

How can is set the indices correctly (if possible) so when I run:

```py
data.sel(time="2022-01-01")
```

I get a subset of the dataset for one time, all locations and one monthly average (which corresponds to the selected time)?

At the moment when I run this I get

[image]

returning all monthly averages for the timestep.

Conversely, when I run

```py
data.sel(month=1)
```

I'd like a subset with only the timesteps that are in January.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selection return what you want, I would first compute the monthly averages and repeat them to match the original time-dimension.
Then I would create a multi-index, such that you can select either the specific date or the month.

```py
#setup test data 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(42)

data = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randint(1,100, (36, 3)), 
    dims=("time", "location"), 
    coords={
        "time": pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=36, freq="10D"), 
        "location": ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    name="observations"
)

#compute monthly array and repeat with list comprehension
data=data.to_dataset()
monthly_avg = data.groupby("time.month").mean()['observations'].values
data['average']=(('time','location'),np.array([monthly_avg[i-1,:] for i in data.time.dt.month]))

#add month  and create multiindex
data['month']=data.time.dt.month
data=data.set_index(day_month=['time','month'])
```

You can then run the selection to get what you want.

```py
print(data.sel(time="2022-01-01"))
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (location: 3, month: 1)
Coordinates:
  * location      (location) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'
  * month         (month) int64 1
    time          <U10 '2022-01-01'
Data variables:
    observations  (month, location) int64 52 93 15
    average       (month, location) float64 70.5 82.25 33.75
```

```py
print(data.sel(month=1))
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (location: 3, time: 4)
Coordinates:
  * location      (location) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 2022-01-11 ... 2022-01-31
    month         int64 1
Data variables:
    observations  (time, location) int64 52 93 15 72 61 21 83 87 75 75 88 24
    average       (time, location) float64 70.5 82.25 33.75 ... 70.5 82.25 33.7
```

This gives repeated values for the second command.

Maybe there is a better way to set up the multi-index.
You can have a look at the pandas multiindex documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html:
or into stack/unstack in xarray: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.7.2/reshaping.html#stack-and-unstack
in case you haven't done so before.